# [PHP/IIS FastCGI]: Error after installing FastCGI and PHP 5.3.0 nts on windows

Tags: php, fastcgi

I am getting following errors when I try to execute any PHP application after I installed IIS FastCGI and PHP 5.3.0 non-thread-safe on Windows XP:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
load dynamic library 'C:\Program
Files\PHP\ext\php_enchant.dll' - The
specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
load dynamic library 'C:\Program
Files\PHP\ext\php_oci8.dll' - The
specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
load dynamic library 'C:\Program
Files\PHP\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' -
The specified module could not be
found.  in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
load dynamic library 'C:\Program
Files\PHP\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The
specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0
```

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check that the offending `dll`s actually are there in the `ext` folder
2. Check that in your `php.ini` the `extension_dir` value is enclosed by quotes
3. Finally, check the documentation of those extensions for additional dependencies (e.g. I recall the Oracle extensions requiring some `dll`s that come with the Oracle client...)